# Error en plantilla: invalid use of incomplete type

Tags: c++, c++11

Encontré esto en Internet:

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

namespace details {

template< typename F, typename Tuple, bool Done, int Total, int... N > struct call_impl {
  static void call( F f, Tuple && t ) {
    call_impl< F, Tuple, Total == 1 + sizeof...( N ), Total, N..., sizeof...( N ) >::call( f, std::forward< Tuple >( t ) );
  }
};

template< typename F, typename Tuple, int Total, int... N > struct call_impl< F, Tuple, true, Total, N... > {
  static void call( F f, Tuple && t ) {
    f( std::get< N >( std::forward< Tuple >( t ) )... );
  }
};

} // namespace details.

template< typename F, typename Tuple > void call( F f, Tuple &&t ) {
  //typedef typename std::decay< Tuple >::type ttype;
  using ttype = typename std::decay< Tuple >::type;

  details::call_impl< F, Tuple, 0 == std::tuple_size< ttype >::value, std::tuple_size< ttype >::value >::call( f, std::forward< Tuple >( t ) );
}
```

Sirve para *desempaquetar* una `std::tuple` sobre los argumentos de una llamada a función.

La idea es *posponer* una llamada a función hasta que sea necesario, almacenando los argumentos pasados en una `std::tuple` y pudiendo recuperarlos en un momento posterior.

Desafortunadamente, la `template` solo trabaja con funciones `void`. La estoy intentando adaptar para poder usarla en funciones con cualquier tipo de retorno, pero no lo estoy consiguiendo:

> error: no matching function for call to 'call(int (&)(int), std::tuple<int>&)'
>   ...
>   error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class std::result_of<int (*)(int)>'

```
#include <tuple>
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>

#include <iostream>

namespace details {

template< typename RET, typename F, typename Tuple, bool Done, int Total, int... N > struct call_impl {
  static RET call( F f, Tuple && t ) {
    return call_impl< RET, F, Tuple, Total == 1 + sizeof...( N ), Total, N..., sizeof...( N ) >::call( f, std::forward< Tuple >( t ) );
  }
};

template< typename RET, typename F, typename Tuple, int Total, int... N > struct call_impl< RET, F, Tuple, true, Total, N... > {
  static RET call( F f, Tuple && t ) {
    return f( std::get< N >( std::forward< Tuple >( t ) )... );
  }
};

} // namespace details.

template< typename F, typename Tuple, typename RET = typename std::result_of< F >::type > RET call( F f, Tuple &&t ) {
  //typedef typename std::decay< Tuple >::type ttype;
  using ttype = typename std::decay< Tuple >::type;

  return details::call_impl< RET, F, Tuple, 0 == std::tuple_size< ttype >::value, std::tuple_size< ttype >::value >::call( f, std::forward< Tuple >( t ) );
}

int dummy( int );

int main( ) {
  auto tp = std::make_tuple( 10 );
  auto ret = call( dummy, tp );

  std::cout << "Retorno: " << ret << std::endl;

  return 0;
}

int dummy( int v ) {
  std::cout << "dummy( " << v << " )\n";
  return v + 1;
}
```

<sub>**Nota:** compilado con `g++ -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11 -pedantic`</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que `F` como tal no contiene la firma de la función sino el tipo asociado a la misma... para deducir el valor de retorno es necesario pasarle los parámetros (piensa, por ejemplo, en el caso de funciones sobrecargadas).

Peeero claro, no le puedes pasar los parámetros porque están contenidos dentro de la tupla:

```
template< typename F, typename Tuple, typename RET = typename std::result_of< F >::type > RET call( F f, Tuple &&t ) {
//                             ^^^^^
```

Así pues necesitamos extraer esos parámetros para ser capaces de deducir el tipo de retorno.

Seguramente se pueda dejar más bonito, pero ahora mismo no tengo tiempo de limpiar el código mucho más.

El código no va a compilar, tal y como está planteado, con la sintaxis *move*, por eso he quitado esa característica... pero estoy trabajando en ello:

```
template< typename F, typename ... Args, typename ReturnType = typename std::result_of<F&(Args...)>::type>
ReturnType call( F const& f, std::tuple<Args...> t ) {
  using ttype = typename std::decay<std::tuple<Args...>>::type;

  return details::call_impl<ReturnType, F, std::tuple<Args...> , 0 == std::tuple_size< ttype >::value, std::tuple_size< ttype >::value >::call( f, std::forward< std::tuple<Args...> >( t ) );
}
```